# Adding ones to n-dimensional numpy array at the beginning and at the end of each row

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a NumPy array `data` of dimensions:

```
(100,2048)
```

I would like to add 11 ones at the beginning and 11 ones the end of each row.

to get `data.shape = (100, 11+2048+11)`

I tried the following :

```
y = np.array([[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]])
z = np.append(y, data[0], axis=0)
```

It works for the first `data[0]` by adding zeros from the left.
However, I fail to add on the right side even for only one row.

I'm looking for something like :

```
 z = np.append([y, data,y], axis=0)
```

For instance:

```
z[0]= [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,
.......................,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
```

..... means the 2048 values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new array with zeros and fill it at needed locations:

```
offset = 11
z = np.ones((data.shape[0], data.shape[1] + offset * 2), dtype=data.dtype)
z[:, offset:z.shape[1] - offset] = data
```

Comment: Thank you @Mike. It works well but l need that with ones not zeros. However if np.ones() will alter my 2048 values

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html):

```
np.pad(z, ((0,0),(11,11)), 'constant', constant_values=1)
```

Explanation: `((0,0), (11,11))`  indicates the number of values padded to the edges of each axis. Here we pad 0 values before and 0 values after axis 0 (the rows) and 11 before and after each column. For the padding we use the constant value 1.

Comment: Original :) So, is `np.pad` an alias to `np.lib.pad`? Even the examples in numpy docs use `np.lib.pad`

Comment: @kmario23 not sure why the docs use `np.lib.pad`. Both `np.pad` and `np.lib.pad` work anyway.